# Fetch facebook inbox messages

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch the inbox messages of the logged in users. I have tried the following code as described in the facebook devlopers website, but I'm getting an error response.

```
FB.api(
    "/me/inbox",
    function (response) {

    if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
        alert(response);
    }
    else {
        alert("this part is getting alerted");
    }})
```

But when i tried it in graph api explorer i am getting the data correctly
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Finbox&version=v2.1

Comment: And the error response is....

Comment: when i tried to alert reponse.error , i am getting undefined....but what i mean is...in the above code else part is getting executed which is the error part is not it?

Comment: Just log the whole `response`object to console, and inspect it there …

Comment: ok..i wil try and let you know.

Comment: sorry i am not able to do that..

Comment: Why not? What error do you get? Can you create a working demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/isyedabu/cmh27v8c/